# Model-First with Existing DB. New DB always attempts to be created. Results in 'CREATE TABLE permission denied in database'

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I created a model-first diagram pointing to a couple of views on an existing DB. When I attempt to query said DB, EF attempts to create & update said DB (despite being told not to).

As with many existing DBs one wants to query, I have SELECT permissions, but not DB create permissions. I don't want EF mucking with creating ANY objects for this particular DB (MyDb)

There are a couple of strange things:
1. The model shouldn't need to update the DB (it matches the view)
2. Database.SetInitializer(null) //Set on MVC Application_Start
3. To troubleshoot, added. doesExist returns true, so EF should not attempt to create DB. Doubly so with the SetInitializer set.

```
        using (var myDb = new MyDBContext1())
        {
            bool doesExist = myDb.Database.Exists(); //return true, the DB does exist!
        }
```

I hope I am wrong, but this seems like a initializer bug in EF that is not honoring my preferences. Please prove me wrong :)

About my setup:
-Using Visual Studio 2013 Preview and EF6 Beta 1
-There is another "Code First" model and DBContext2 (for another DB) in the project. This DB I do own and can create/update the DB to match model changes (if I want to)
-DBContext2 had for some time Code Migrations turned on for it. I deleted all the config and migration table, thinking it may indirectly affect the other context (MyDBContext1), but it didn't help.

--Stack Trace--
//Why is DBMigration and AutoMigrate running here??

//Of course permissions are denied. I don't have SA access  (nor need it) to this particular DB that 
. I just want to run SELECT statements on.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232060
  Message=CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDb'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=14
  LineNumber=1
  Number=262
  Procedure=""
  Server=MyDBServer
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TResult](Func`1 operation, Action`1 executing, Func`3 executed)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<ExecuteStatements>b__2b()
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 func)
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass9.<Update>b__8()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(Boolean skipExistsCheck)
       at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassc`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__b()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
.....
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a static initializer in `MyDBContext1`?

```
static MyDBContext1()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDBContext1>(null);
}
```